# PHP file upload not working properly, how to fix?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm working on a website and this page has a form submission including a file upload, the form is going from html to php to mysql without an issue but the file upload doesn't seem to want to process.

HTML (inside a form posting to submit):

```
Document: <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" required></br></br>
```

PHP (without mysql start):

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$FileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($FileType != "doc" && $FileType != "docx" && $FileType != "pdf") {
    echo "Sorry, only DOC, DOCX, & PDF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";

// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

The error either kicks at the filetype or just at the bottom. I couldn't find a php.ini anywhere on the server.

Thanks for your time, should I just make a php.ini?

Edit: Here's the print_r($_FILES);

[image]

Comment: *"The error either kicks at the filetype or just at the bottom."* - What error?  Please be specific and detailed in the description of the problem, including what your debugging has revealed and where specifically the unexpected behavior first happens in the code.

Comment: Since it's not clear, does your form have enctype="multipart/form-data" ?

Comment: Sorry about that, there's no actual error I misspoke. It tends to echo "Sorry, only DOC, DOCX, & PDF files are allowed." even when it is a docx. and If that section is commented out it echos "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file."

Comment: It actually didn't @imvain2, however I've added it and it didn't fix it. It's now just echo'ing "Sorry there was an error uploading your file" meaning it now makes it all the way through.

Comment: `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["fullname"]` should be `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]` files array does not have ''fullname". Add `print_r($_FILES)` so see what you actually have to work with

Comment: @tim I've actually already made that adjustment, I'll reflect it in the code above.

Comment: indulge me, add `print_r($_FILES)`, and paste your result.

Comment: @Nick , what is the erro you have ?

Comment: @tim you got it man, https://i.imgur.com/hkBlYPL.png

Comment: its not showing the error you said it does "Sorry, only DOC, DOCX, & PDF files are allowed."

Comment: if its a move_uploaded_file issue that's usually directory permissions,

Comment: @tim that went away when I added enctype to the html form, which was one big relief. Now it's just the "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file" and the error that displays in the print_r image

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning, so you'll see the warning message that explains why `move_uploaded_file` failed.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? This is untested, I just took out your filetype check and replaced it using an array.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$allowed_types =array('doc','docx','pdf')
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$FileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
$error = null;

// Get the file extension
$ext = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Search the array for the allowed file type

if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if (in_array($ext, $allowed_types, false) != true) {
    $error = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    return $error; // or use  exit;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";

// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been 
uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Don't just post code. Explain what was wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: as OP explained in the comments the file type detection is not the error any more

Comment: @tim yeah I substituted this code just to see it, yet again ""Sorry, there was an error uploading your file." could this be an upload_file = allow or whatever the syntax is in a php.ini

Comment: @Nick as said above move_uploaded_file will report the issue, just make sure you are displaying that level of errors,